# Pythonのプログラムを実行すると SyntaxError: invalid syntax が出る

Tags: python

初めまして。
プログラミング初心者としPythonを勉強している者です。

“*（星マーク）”を使って、コマンドライン上で入力したパラメータ（数字のみ）に応じて高さの異なるピラミッドのような図をコマンド上に表示するというコードを作る練習をしています。

パラメータの入力をしなかった場合、print文で自分で用意したエラーメッセージを表示するようにしたいのですが、私が書いたコードではそのためのif文の部分でエラーメッセージが表示されます。

**エラーメッセエージ**

```
  File "LabOrientation2.py", line 6
    if height = None
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

下記に私のコードを書きますので、どのように間違っているのか、どうすればコードが動くかご指摘ご教授願えませんでしょうか？

**実行したコード**

```
from sys import argv

def pyramid(height):
    if height < 0:
        print ("ERROR: Number must be non-negative.")
    if height = None 
        print ("ERROR: Please provide parameter.")
    for i in range(height):
        print (" " * (height-i-1) + "*" * (2*i+1))

pyramid(int(argv[1]))
```

Comment: 後尾の「:」が抜けています。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if height = None
```

この行の末尾にコロンが必要です。また、代入に使う演算子である `=` と比較につかう演算子である `==` を取り違えています。

```
if height == None:
```

もっと言うと、[None との比較には `is` を使うべき](https://pep8-ja.readthedocs.io/ja/latest/#id41)です。

```
if height is None:
```

`SyntaxError: invalid syntax` というエラーは、シンタックスエラー、つまりプログラムの表面上の構文が間違っており、Python 処理系が解釈できなかったというエラーです。このエラーが出たときは何かしらプログラムの書き方を間違っていないか注意すると良いです。

Comment: = を == に変更する必要もあります。Pythonの場合は、Noneとの比較は  is を使うべきです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。回答に反映させました。

Comment: ご指摘、ご教授下さりありがとうございます。コロンの追加、比較にisを書いてもう一度コマンド内でパラメーターの入力をわざとしないではしらせてみたところ、コード内のエラーメッセージではなく、“Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "LabOrientation2.py", line 11, in <module>
    pyramid(int(argv[1]))
IndexError: list index out of range”　というエラーメッセージが出ました。私の書いたコード内のメッセージが表示されるようにするにはどうしたらよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: なるほど、新しい問題が出てきたのですね。この問題は元の問題と少しだけ異なるものなので、ご面倒ですが新しい質問として再度ご投稿いただけないでしょうか。その際、プログラムをどのように実行されたかの情報があると嬉しいです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。質問を改めて後ほど新しく投稿します。初めてこのサイトを利用するので、色々至らない点も多いですが、どうぞよろしくお願い申し上げます。